# Two Count queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I am checking count of two table in this code. both the queries are working individually but writing them like this always gives error.

```
<?php
require 'db/userWrite.php';


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$today = new DateTime("now");
$last = new DateTime("20.03.14");

$fquery = "SELECT count(*) as female FROM female_athletes";
$fresult = $db->prepare($fquery);
$fresult->execute();
$fresult->bind_result($female);
$fresult->fetch();
var_dump($fresult);

$mquery = "SELECT count(*) as male FROM male_athletes";
$m = $db->prepare($mquery);
$m->execute();
$m->bind_result($male);
$m->fetch();
```

Result

> object(mysqli_stmt)#4 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1)
>   ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0)
>   ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000"
>   ["id"]=> int(1) }

**Notice: Undefined variable: m in /home/.... on line**

**Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/... on line**

Comment: your prepare call for the `male` query failed and returned false - probably because you've still got the query for the female open and running.  Try doing `var_dump($db->errorInfo())` after the male prepare call

Comment: that'd be a PHP error. Can't see anything wrong with your above code though. Are you sure it's an exact cut 'n paste of the actual code? Which line is the "undefined variable" bit coming from?

Comment: @MarcB exact same output as file is not read till that point where i added this. error is where i prepare mquery and line where i execute it[$m->execute();]

Comment: @MarcB yea i am sure about that.

Comment: Your first error is before this code already – instead of having _two_ tables `female_athletes` and `male_athletes`, you should have __one__ table `athletes` with an attribute column for `female` or `male`. And then you can just run a query with `COUNT` on the records `GROUP(ed) BY` that attribute.

Comment: got new warning **Warning: mysqli::prepare(): All data must be fetched before a new statement prepare takes place**

Comment: I don't think that will be fine(make one table) i have a requirement to only register 60 male and 60 female. and even if i merge them i will have to do two queries again to count.. count where gender is female and then male

Comment: Try doing `$fresult->close()` after `$fresult->fetch();`

Comment: @user3361436: it'd still only be one query: `select sex, count(*) from mergedtable group by sex`.